# What templates are available for generating an elisp library?

Tags: yasnippet, libraries, skeleton

At some point I remember encountering a command that generated a skeleton of a properly formatted emacs-lisp library as below:

```
;;; library.el --- summary

;; Copyright ...

;; Author:
;; Keywords:

;; License

;;; Commentary:
;; 

;;; Code:

(provide 'library)

;;; library.el ends here
```

After some searching I found `checkdoc`, which prompts for summary, and commentary and code. Is that the only template generation for a new emacs lisp library builtin to emacs core? Are there any tempo or skeleton based templates for a new emacs lisp library builtin to Emacs core, or somewhere else with yasnippet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remembered it was `auto-insert-mode`. Make a new elisp file, run `M-x auto-insert`, and it prompts for summary, author, inserts the license and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you found your answer.  But you might also want to look at library [`header2.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el).

It doesn't prompt you for anything. But it can automatically provide a customized file header for a new file. And it can automatically update the header (e.g. when you save the file).  Unlike the example you show, by default it does not insert any code - just comments.  But that too you can customize.